# Group key-value pairs and get count using Counter in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, counter

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
res = [{"isBlack": "yes"} , {"isWhite": "no"} , {"isRed": "yes"} , {"isWhite": "yes"} , {"isRed": "no"} , {"isBlack": "yes"}]
```

I need to group res by key-value pair and get their count using Counter , to look like this:

```
Counter({"isBlack:yes": 2 , "isWhite:no": 1, "isWhite:yes": 1 , "isRed:no": 1 , "isRed:yes": 1})
```

I tried this:
`count = Counter(res)` , but getting error like:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do some preprocessing in a generator expression to convert the dicts to strings.

```
print(Counter(f"{next(iter(d))}:{d[next(iter(d))]}" for d in res))
```

`next(iter(d))` is to get the first key in a dictionary (which happens to be the only one here).

Comment: Thank you @SuperStormer...Your solution worked just perfectly.
Earlier error was wrong by my side, as I gave wrong input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dict.popitem` method to obtain the item tuple in each sub-dict first and then join the tuple into a colon-delimited string to pass on to `Counter`:

```
Counter(':'.join(d.popitem()) for d in res)
```

This returns:

```
Counter({'isBlack:yes': 2, 'isWhite:no': 1, 'isRed:yes': 1, 'isWhite:yes': 1, 'isRed:no': 1})
```

Alternatively, instead of using a colon-delimited string as a key, it would be more idiomatic to make the key-value tuples as generated by the `dict.items()` method the keys:

```
Counter(i for d in res for i in d.items())
```

This returns:

```
Counter({('isBlack', 'yes'): 2, ('isWhite', 'no'): 1, ('isRed', 'yes'): 1, ('isWhite', 'yes'): 1, ('isRed', 'no'): 1})
```